# SpEl (Spring Expression Language) Extracting Substring

Tags: regex, spring, spring-el

I have a 'relative-filename' parameter in a Spring Integration Message Header.

It could be formatted like

"/tmp/frodo/files/pending/whatever.xml" or
"/tmp/wilfred/files/completed/new/another.xml"

The portion **before** "files" can be of variable length...

I was using an expression like:

headers['relative-filename'].substring(11,) to get the part of the string **including and after**
"files" ("files" is always there) .... this works for "frodo", but not for "wilfred".

How do I get the part of the string after "files"?

Can one have a variable expression as the first index of the "substring" or is there a regex that will prune the first portion of the file?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work for all paths having two names before the `files` part, regardless of  their lenght:

```
^(\/.*?\/.*?\/)files(.*)$
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://regex101.com/r/lU1eT4)

Comment: I am not a big "regex" person (I haven't studied them as in depth as I should and I REALLY should do this), but this is a really elegant solution.   Thanks.  It fits very nicely in the SpEl that I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf()` and `length()` in your expression. 7 is a length of searched text. This is an example:

```
 before: "'a/files/b'.substring(0, 'a/files/b'.indexOf('/files/'))"
 after: "'a/files/b'.substring('a/files/b'.indexOf('/files/') + 7, 'a/files/b'.length())"
```

Comment: Thank you very much.... Tested the concept and it works.  Am looking at the "regex" solution also.